# Sending email from Azure website, only timeouts, running out of ideas

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure

We have an Azure hosted website that is trying to send mail over SMTP.

All I get is timeouts, here are my POP and IMAP settings followed by code. In Azure portal under the website - do i need to configure anything in Azure website settings?

[image: POP and IMAP settings from Office365 site]

My c# code below...The code uses the following values it fetches from the database :

[image]

```
public bool Send(string sRecipient, string sSubject, string sBody)
{
    CompanyProvider obj = _db.GetCompanyProvider();

    if (!obj.EmailNotifications) 
        return true;


    MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
    mail.To.Add(sRecipient);
    mail.From = new MailAddress(obj.SenderEmail);
    mail.Subject = sSubject;
    string Body = sBody;
    mail.Body = Body;
    mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
    SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
    smtp.Host = obj.SMTPHost;
    smtp.Port = obj.SMTPPort;
    smtp.Timeout = 8;
    smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
    smtp.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
    smtp.EnableSsl = true;
    smtp.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(obj.SenderEmail, obj.SenderEmailPassword);// Enter senders User name and password
    //smtp.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential
        //(obj.SenderEmail.Substring(0, obj.SenderEmail.IndexOf('@')), obj.SenderEmailPassword);// Enter senders User name and password


    try
        {
            smtp.Send(mail);
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _db.writeToErrorLog(ex.ToString(), "Unable to send mail at this time");
            return false;
        }

}
```

}

Comment: Can you provide the full exception?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using Azure websites.....

http://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/sendgrid-dotnet-how-to-send-email/